# How to redirect the request to another controller after successful ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

Here is my code

```
    $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e){
          var info = $(this).serialize();
          $.ajax(
          {
              url : "ctrl1",
              type: "post",
              data : info,
              success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
              {
                    $('.valid-error').html(data);
                    if(data == "success"){
                          $.get("ctrl2", info); // this get request do not come to the servlet
                    }
              }
          });
          e.preventDefault() 
        });
$(".submit").click(function(){
      $("#ajaxform").submit();
});
```

how to redirect the request to another controller after successful ajax request and data == "success"? I have breakpoint in my servlet's doGet() and it is not called. The code here does not work i tested it. How to make this get request work?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e){
          var info = $(this).serialize();
          $.ajax(
          {
              url : "ctrl1",
              type: "GET",
              async: false,
              data : info,
              success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
              {
                    $('.valid-error').html(data);
                    if(data == "success"){

                           window.location.href = "/Controllername/Viewname";
                    }
              }
          });
          e.preventDefault() 
        });
$(".submit").click(function(){
      $("#ajaxform").submit();
});
```

Here to specify your controller name and view name

Comment: it will not make a get request and my servlet get method will be not called. I tried it.

Comment: @oronaparcali any default request is GET request to the method of the controller , why do think it is not making get call ?

Comment: because I have break point in my servlets doGet() method and it is not going there.

Answer (score 0):

In controller instead of JavascriptResult Use IActionResult

In Js Use like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '//',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: { Your data },
    success: function (data) {
        window.location.href = "/Home/Index";
    }
});
```